# No Rsync With DigitalOcean and Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, rsync, digital-ocean

I've been trying to get this working, and I don't know if I've just missed the configuration or if this is an actual bug since there seem to be similar ones.

I'm using Vagrant to manage a DigitalOcean VPS, and although it will create and sync things fine when I first start the machine, including creating or deleting files based on the local version, using "vagrant rsync" seems to do nothing. This is intended as a web server, so rebooting every time a release needs to be done doesn't really work, but I'm not sure how I can work it without rsync.

My Vagrantfile is pasted below, anyone with more Vagrant experience know what might be wrong or suggest an alternative?

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "digital_ocean"

  config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"

  config.vm.provider :digital_ocean do |provider|
    provider.token = "xxxxx"
    # CentOS 7 image
    provider.image = "10322623"
    provider.region = "lon1"
    provider.size = "1gb"
  end

  config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www/public_html", type: "rsync"

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'd missed that the vagrant rsync command doesn't work with the digital ocean plugin. vagrant provision seems to be the one to use, just need to make sure it's set up so the yum commands check software is present rather than most recent

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on what you did to resolve this?  I'm not sure what you mean by "vagrant provision seems to be the one to use"  Maybe add the code block for your provision?

Comment: The DigitalOcean plugin doesn't allow you to use rsync, it's not a command that's been enabled (at least not integrated into vagrant). The "vagrant provision" command lets you synchronise your files though, so I just used that. You need to make sure that your provisioning software (eg ansible or puppet) only checks that the software is present rather than up to date though, otherwise this will also update the software on your server